# The function 'bigrams' in python nltk not working

Tags: python, nltk

The function bigrams from nltk is returning the following message,

even though nltk is imported and other functions from it are working. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
showing info http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/
True
>>> from nltk import bigrams
>>> bigrams(['more', 'is', 'said', 'than', 'done'])
<generator object bigrams at 0x0000000002E64240>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `bigrams` has returned a "generator" object; this is a Python data type which is like a List but which only creates its elements as they are needed. If you want to realise a generator as a list, you need to explicitly cast it as a list:

```
>>> list(bigrams(['more', 'is', 'said', 'than', 'done']))
[('more', 'is'), ('is', 'said'), ('said', 'than'), ('than', 'done')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Comment: @DRG, since the answer solved your problem, you should now "accept" it by clicking on the big checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

```
<generator object bigrams at 0x0000000002E64240>
```

when this instruction appears it means that your bigrams are created and they are ready to be displayed. Now if you want them to display just put your instruction as:

```
list(bigrams(['more', 'is', 'said', 'than', 'done']))
```

which means that you need bigrams as output in the form of list and you will get:

```
[('more', 'is'), ('is', 'said'), ('said', 'than'), ('than', 'done')]
```